# Cannot retrieve recordset returned from stored procedure in MS Access ADO

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I'm working on an old MS-Access (2007) application (maintenance + changes). The current change involves changing a piece of code from a `select * from` to the invocation of a stored procedure that returns a simple table (one varchar column only).

Here is the part of the code within MS-Access:

```
:
Set Conn1 = CurrentProject.Connection
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1
Cmd1.CommandText = "p_Labels_Print"
Cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@_p_Button_type", adInteger, adParamInput)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@_p_Sampling_Request", adInteger, adParamInput)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@_p_Place", adVarChar, adParamInput, 16)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@_p_Sampler_Code", adVarChar, adParamInput, 16)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@_p_Total_Copies", adInteger, adParamInput)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@_p_Print_Option", adInteger, adParamInput)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@_p_Print_Option", adVarChar, adParamInput, 16)

Cmd1.Parameters(0).Value = 2
Cmd1.Parameters(1).Value = 2878954
Cmd1.Parameters(2).Value = "0C9991"
Cmd1.Parameters(3).Value = 89029
Cmd1.Parameters(4).Value = 10
Cmd1.Parameters(5).Value = 1
Cmd1.Parameters(6).Value = "S-SAPTEST"
Set Rs1 = Cmd1.Execute()


 ' Process results from recordset, then close it.
 :
 Rs1.Close
 :
```

Now, I know that the procedure is invoked with the correct parameters (and values since I'm logging from within the procedure into a debug table, and I see that all the parameters are received and that the returned table contains exactly 10 records (as parameter "4" stipulates).

The returned table looks like:

```
 +------------------------------------------------------+
 | One_Sticker                                          |
 +------------------------------------------------------+
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 |WQSticker03@!@2878954@!@KRG000@!@BlaBla-1@!@S-SAPTEST |
 +------------------------------------------------------+
```

Within MS-Access, I set a breakpoint at the statement `Rs1.Close` and a watch on `Rs1`. Then, when digging into the results within `Rs1` there is nothing (meaning `Fields > Count 0` within the watch window for Rs1).

Am I missing something (like defining in some way the variable other than `Rs1`) to receive the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The statement:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON ;
```

was missing at the beginning of the invoked stored procedure. Once added, everything started to work as expected.